# Can I see IP address that connected with my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-transfer, ddos

I use AWS (Amazon Web Services) and recently I saw a very large outbound traffic on Network Out Monitor. How can I see IP addresses that connected with my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to monitor which ip's are accessing your server is to use some application on your server to log the ip's. For example, if you're hosting an apache or iis server you'll need to look at those respective logs to find the ip. Amazon does not provide any information about who is connecting to your servers.

Comment: Yes, that's completely true. I suppose "Network Out" also gets pretty lively when you're sending data from your EC2 instance to another EC2 instance, or even to another Amazon Web Service such as S3, though, so this may not always show up in the Apache logs.

Comment: My network out usage last month was 29,000GB it was all internal traffic, none of it logged. The only thing is i know exactly where it came from because its all internal. External connects have to connect to some application. Whatever application that is must have some log. 

I suppose its possible they managed to log in and transfer some file, but there's still probably traces of that somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying the "Network Out" CloudWatch statistics in the AWS control panel only show data actually leaving the network of the AWS facility? I don't think that's entirely true, I think it catches traffic from EC2 to S3 (or any other service) within the same AWS facility too...but I haven't tested. I'm just saying that the OP's "very large outbound traffic" may just have been himself moving some data between AWS services. Other than that, yours is a complete answer, of course :)

Comment: No, the Network Out is instance based. Data transferred out of the instance no matter where its headed even if its the same availability zone or region will be recorded. This is not necessarily the value you get billed on, some data being transferred is free depending on the target location.